# How to get an access to SASS variables in Slim, HAML etc.?

Tags: sass, haml, slim-lang, middleman

How to get an access to SASS variables & mixins which are stored in the assets directory of project directly from HTML-preprocessors (Slim, HAML)?

I mean how to make work things like this:

```
// Ruby Slim
style
    sass:
        @import 'lib/vars'
        body
            background: $color
```

producing:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #fff
    }
 </style>
```

whereas `$color` is defined somewhere in `lib/_vars.sass` and equals to `#fff`.

Why do I need it? Well, I need it for page-specific styles and elements and I do not want to store them in global styles.

It doesn't work for me in Middleman+Slim+SASS+Compass environment. Ruby just says:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: lib/vars.
```

Comment: I don't *think* it's possible to get HAML variables to SASS

Comment: No, no, not HAML, but SASS.

Comment: So from SASS to HAML?

Comment: OK, maybe my English in not good enough to explain it correctly so I'll try to express more clearly :-) So, I have a typical project with a .sass with vars which is imported to an app's main .sass that compiling into a app's .css as is commonplace. But I need some in-HTML styles which may also use global SASS variables. I do not want to write CSS manually to keep things consistently. I would like to use all SASS' power even in a such particular case. So I ask if there's a way to do this. Because it doesn't work right now like it should be.

Comment: So yes, from SASS to HAML, you're right.

Comment: That's not possible. You should give elements a class and style that class in your SASS

Comment: Oh, thank you, but why not, don't you know?

Comment: Because there is no use? Using a class and applying styles to the class does what I'm understanding you want

Comment: Yes, but what if do not want to manually redifine the bunch of my variables, mixins (clearfix, font-sizes for example) etc. It could be useful even there. But anyway it doesn't work.

Comment: Why you would need font-sizes etc. in your HAML anyway?

Comment: You should extend Sass load path with the location of your Sass partials from where you run Slim.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wish there was a better answer but, unfortunately, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with Sass 3.  Review [this article](http://technology.customink.com/blog/2014/10/09/understanding-and-using-sass-load-paths/), which will have you:

1. Use the [sass_paths](http://sass_paths) gem to manipulate the ENV var that holds the lookup paths
2. Add an initializer that appends your path to the ENV var

For example:

```
# config/initializers/sass_paths.rb
require 'sass_paths'

# append a directory, or list of directories to SASS_PATH
SassPaths.append("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @steakchaser said it's possible using the [sass_path](https://github.com/customink/sass_paths) gem, but if you don't have any trouble fiddling with the ENV variable (`SASS_PATH`) yourself, you can also do a simple append like this:

```rb
# in config/initializers/assets.rb for example
ENV['SASS_PATH'] = ["app/assets/stylesheets", ENV['SASS_PATH'].presence].compact.join(':')
```

After that, imports from the added folder will work with Slim and HAML inline style tags.